# Simulating Textbox BorderBrush for a Border

Tags: wpf, textbox, border

I need a `Border` to have a `BorderBrush` just like a default `TextBox` has. It should be changed while mouse is over and when some element within the border get focused.

Right near the `Border`, there is a `TextBox` with the default style. I tried this code, it works only at the normal state.

```
<Border BorderBrush="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, ElementName=txtName}"
        BorderThickness="{Binding Path=BorderThickness, ElementName=txtName}">
    ...
</Border>
<TextBox x:Name="txtName"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to find out which brush is the TextBox style using when you're hovering it (check its default style).

Then you can define your own style for the Border with a trigger for when MouseOver is true that will set the BorderBrush and BorderThickness to the appropiate values.

Comment: So...what will happen if user changes current system colors via control-panel? I need a real dynamic binding.